# How to erase two times elementary OS from my harddisk and install elementary OS again

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, grub

I'm a totally beginner, but I am facing a crazy complicate problem.

The Story:

1. I installed elementary OS next to my Windows 8 successfully on my Laptop.
2. As a bloody beginner I did a unbelievable stupid mistake and deleted some important parts of the system.
3. I still had saved all my Documents, i like elementary OS anyway more than windows, so I decided to reinstall elementary OS again, this time on my whole computer, I hoped to delete windows and the broken OS this way.
4. I chose "format everything and install elementary" in the installing-menu.
5. But now my laptop starts still with dual-boot-menu. Instead of choosing between windows and elementary OS, he ask if I want to start in elementary OS or elementary OS Freya, very weird.
6. I searched for help in the Internet and tried to ask in some
   Linux-forums but as person that starts to learn the very basic
   things about Linux and computer stuff in general just a week ago I
   was lost. Somehow I didn't know for what I have to ask for and so I got
   not-useful answers, somehow the answers was pretty complicate and
   let me again alone.
7. Anyway I learned a lot so I try another question here, that hopefully lead me successfully to the solution.

So that's my new question: I want to reinstall elementary OS again and format my *two* harddisks. I want to use gparted in the installing-menu for that. How can I make sure that the new installed elementary OS will find both harddisks and use both?

This is how my harddisks are partitioned at the moment:

> Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54505 (scsi)
>   Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
>   Partition Table: gpt
>
> Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
>
> 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32                 boot
>
> 2      538MB   496GB  495GB   ext4
>
> 3      496GB   500GB  4153MB  linux-swap(v1)
>
> Model: ATA LITEONIT LMT-32L (scsi)
>   Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0GB
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
>   Partition Table: gpt
>
> Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
>
> 1      1049kB  8589MB  8588MB                  Basic data partition
>
> 2      8589MB  9127MB  538MB   fat32                                 boot
>
> 3      9127MB  27.9GB  18.7GB  ext4
>
> 4      27.9GB  32.0GB  4153MB  linux-swap(v1)

Thank you very very much for your help, it would give me back all the fun with elementary, because in the moment it's mainly frustrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Install elementary on the LITEON disk. Use the other disk for your personal files and swap.

Long answer:
The use of two different drives may seem complicated, but this is actually going to be very useful for you.
You have two different drives: the 32 GB Liteon is an **SSD** and the 500 GB Hitachi is a more traditional **HDD**. I suppose Windows was installed on the SSD: the reason is that while more expensive (hence the smaller size), an SDD is much faster. You want to install the OS and apps on an SDD to have fast loading times, and keep all you personal files on the HDD because of the larger space.

Now, to partition your drive:

```
LITEONIT LMT-32L:
All the space in ext4 for the root of your system (choose "/" as mount point)

Hitachi HTS54505
4153MB linux-swap
All the rest in ext4 for your personal files (choose "/home" as mount point)
```

If any of this seems complicated, or if you have further questions, **or any doubts at all**, don't hesitate: ask for help. The amount of knowledge you need to use linux is pretty low, but the amount of knowledge you need to actually install linux is *insanely high*.

For further reference:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Thank you so much Henri, that was the final explanation i needed! you rescued my computer, my os and my motivation for linux! i added as well a efi-partition on the ssd of 150 MB, cause the programm told me i need a root-partition. everything else i did like you said and now my computer is running pretty fast and have just one elementary <3. the link you posted is the most understandable explanation i found.

Comment: You're much welcome, tink.